# Are the Given Metrics Complete or Not?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Which of the following metric spaces are complete?
>
> 1. $X_1=(0,\frac{\pi}{2}), d(x,y)=|\tan x-\tan y|$
> 2. $X_2=[0,1], d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$
> 3. $X_3=\mathbb{Q}, d(x,y)=1\forall x\neq y$
> 4. $X_4=\mathbb{R}, d(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$

My answer :  option  $2$ and  $3 $ only  .

Here is the link of question see $3.9 $ https://www.imsc.res.in/~office/nbhm/qp/nbhmra06.pdf

answer key link : see 3. 9 https://www.imsc.res.in/~office/nbhm/qp/nbhmra06key.pdf

My confusion is that  they have  given option $1,2,3 $

I  Just need  conformation  that answer key right or wrong

Comment: why do you think that 2 and 3 are complete, and why 1 and 4 not?

Comment: I seem to think that you are right, but perhaps it would be better to give the Cauchy seqeunces which do not converge, and explain why Cauchy sequences in the other cases converge?

Comment: @miracle173  i have edits see

Comment: @Keen-ameteur  i have edits

Comment: After reviewing again my alledged counter example for (1), I seem to agree with the fact that (1) is complete. What's your counter example?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur take  $x_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ is a cauchy sequence in $X$, $d(x_n,x_m)=|\tan\frac{1}{2^n}-\tan\frac{1}{2^m}|\rightarrow 0\notin X$, so it is not complete

Comment: @miracle173 for  $1$ Consider,  $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and which is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.
But, it converges nowhere in $X$,  if it converges to some $l\in X$ then, its  show that $\tan l=0$ which is not possible

Comment: @Keen-ameteur   reply  me

Comment: I seem to agree with you, and perhaps they meant $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ which is complete? Though I'm no authority.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur  oksss

Comment: You are right. (1) has a Cauchy sequence x_n=1/n that has no limit in X1, (4) has the Cauchy sequence x_n=-n that has no limit in X4- (2) and (3) are complete.